# ReactJS: Property is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

I am new at `React.js` and `typescript`. I tried googling for this issue but could not find any solution for this.

Sidebar.tsx

```
...

import Header from "./Header";

const Sidebar = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <aside className="sidebar">
            <Header title={props.pageTitle} />

            ...
        </aside>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Header.tsx

```
const Header = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img src={ props.image } alt="Logo image" />
        </header>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

How can I fix this issue..?

[image]

Comment: Please give us a hint on where do you import this <Header /> component from, what is it's expected props interface? Otherwise I see not option on how to help about your problem. Usually the problem is related to your typescript props definition of the component.

Comment: The problem is fixed. I mistakenly added the `Header` component in place of `PageHeader` component `AND DID NOT CARE TO CHECK`. I will post the correct code, so that anyone else facing the similar issue can learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed code.

```
...

import Header from "./PageHeader";

const Sidebar = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <aside className="sidebar">
            <PageHeader title={props.pageTitle} />

            ...
        </aside>
    );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

PageHeader.tsx

```
const PageHeader = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <h3 className="heading">{ props.title }</h3>

            ...
        </header>
    )
};

export default PageHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you the  does not have the attribute title.